# OpenGL - Add text without using GLUT

Tags: c, opengl

I want to add characters (x/y/z.., not even strings) to a window using OpenGL, WITHOUT using GLUT. I know about glutBitmapString(), but I want to avoid glut. Any suggestions...?

Answer (score 3):

Last time I did this for a retro-style game, I created a bitmap font and wrote a small routine that would draw a quad with the specific character as a texture on it. Another option is to draw every pixel of the bitmap font in a seperate quad.

You can find example code here:

http://svn.berlios.de/wsvn/pong2/trunk/src/Interface.h
http://svn.berlios.de/wsvn/pong2/trunk/src/Interface.cpp

More specifically:

- `void Interface::createFont()` initiates a bitmap font as a display list for each character
- `void Interface::drawText(const std::string& text)` lets OpenGL call the display lists according to the string's characters

In this specific example, I wanted textured "pixels" within the characters, so each bitmap entry results in its own quad with a stock texture on it. Display lists are nowadays less favored as newer OpenGL features like FBOs and VBOs replace their functionality. I don't know if at some point display lists got deprecated as well.

The text in createFont() was created by The Gimp (http://www.gimp.org) export functionality.

Screenshot to celebrate the 20k: [image: screenshot of retro text rendering]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `glyph map`, which basically boils down to a bitmap texture with a bunch of letters distributed over it.  Load in the texture and draw quads with texture coordinates mapped to the location of the glyph you want in the texture.

There are some drawbacks in a naive implementation that can be partially alleviated.  For example, rather than drawing a ton of quads in separate draw calls, you could take a cue from Java and make immutable strings that tie to a GPU buffer and pack all the `vertices` and `uv`s you need to draw the word into that buffer. (They don't have to be immutable, just know that if you need to make a word longer or shorter, you'll have to reallocate the buffer or leave extra space to put the new letters).

The site that I used whenever I was trying to learn how to do this can be found here:
[Bitmap Fonts](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/bitmapfonts.html)

I have used this method with a WebGL implementation and it has worked quite well.  I even have wrote a tool to generate the texture from a `<canvas>` element on the fly.